# How can I control in which window are open the errors in a compile buffer?

Tags: window-splitting, compile-mode

Summary: How can I control in which window are open the error links in a compile buffer? That is, if I have already 2 windows, I want that the error jumps to the other open window and reuses it for displaying that buffer. It kinda does this but with 2 windows or 4 depending on whether I'm on an external monitor display or the laptop screen.

Long explanation:

I'm trying to configure Emacs to maintain the following setup consistently:

- Keep two windows (I split the frame in two vertically).
- Every time I run compilation it opens it on the other window (the one I'm not active in).

That's it. I'm using [Shackle](https://depp.brause.cc/shackle/) and it sort of helps, but not completely: it works only when I'm using my laptop, but not when using the external monitor. Interestingly, the resolutions are pretty similar:

- Laptop: 3840x2400
- External monitor: 3840x2160

When I'm using the monitor (without extending the laptop, just the monitor), emacs does a similar behavior but instead of respecting the 2-window setup, it always "converges" to a 4-window setup (two on top, two below), no matter where I start. That is, every time I use a message error to go to the corresponding line (in a different file not already open), it will open a buffer (or reuse if there's already 4).

How can I control this? Shackle doesn't let me control things like where do these error links open, which is the main issue.

Comment: What's the value of `shackle-rules`? What is the major mode and name of the file that you are trying to compile?

Comment: ("\\*rustic.*" :regexp t :other t :select nil :align 'right)

I'm using Rustic mode. The name of the file ends with *.rs, does that have anything to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the `window-purpose` package found on `Melpa` may help...

*"Purpose is a package that introduces the concept of a "purpose" for
windows and buffers, and then helps you maintain a robust window
layout easily."*

I'm not used to it enough to give good advices.

Comment: This didn't respond my question directly, but actually helped me solve it in a different way. Having purposed windows does the trick. Thanks!